# cant find device even it is connected after xamarin vs crashed

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

My Visual Studio instantly crashed and after it restarted it is asking for xamarin to be installed. I declined it since I am already using xamarin before it crashed but after that, I saw my main project was unloaded so I tried to load the project again and succeed. But what is so weird is I can't see my device now or even the default emulators for deployment, only start. How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw an answer from xamarin forums - https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/10558/xamarin-android-toolbar-does-not-show-connected-devices and it solved my problem.

It seems that the main project after crashed and restart lose the target as start up project.

This is the part of copied answer

1. Start Windows Visual Studio
2. Open the project
3. Set the Android project as the start up project
4. The device should appear or select it Visual Studio > Menu > Target Android Device
5. Hope that helps, im using a Samsung Galaxy III